# Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell G5 5500

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dell, compatibility

I have just bought a Dell G5 15 5500 (16GB Ram, RTX 2060, i7 10-th gen) with Windows 10 per-installed.

Now I need for work to have Ubuntu on it, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04. Now I have a lot of problems:

- WiFi adapter is not found
- Brightness doesn't work
- No NVIDIA card found
- It blocks when I log in
- Continuously asks for a password

I really need to have Ubuntu 16.04, what can I do?

Comment: Sorry, I always mean 16.04, I have the 16.04.6 LTS version

Comment: Why would you use such an old version of Ubuntu? The kernel used just won't have support for hardware that new. The hardware came out years after that OS was put together. Sorry, but you'd have to do a ton of work to make that work. Don't use Ubuntu 16.04, it's a huge security risk as well to use such an out of date OS that doesn't have security updates anymore.